# why i'm getting stack smashing for the below pgm?

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char s[10] = "hello";
        printf("s = %s\n",s);
}
```

for above pgm i'm getting correct output but for below pgm

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char s[10];
        s[10] = "hello";
        printf("s = %s\n",s);
}
```

for above pgm i'm getting stack smashing
why stack smashing occured.

Comment: `s[10]` does not exist (the 10 array elements are `s[0]`, `s[1]`, ..., `s[9]`). You cannot assign anything to it. Also the type of `s[10]`(`char`, if it existed) and the type of `"hello"` (`char[6]` automatically converted to `char*`) are incompatible.

Comment: `s[10] ` is outside the array bounds and is the wrong type - compiler should tell you the latter. And in C you can't assign a string with `=` (except in the initialisation). Use `strcpy(s, "hello");`

Answer (score 1):

```
s[10] = "hello";
```

1. There is a difference between using `s[10]` at the definition of `s`, and using `s[10]` thereafter. `s[10]` at the definition means you want to define an array of `char` with 10 elements. `s[10]` after the definition of `s` means you want to access the 11th element of array `s`, which does not exist.

   Index counts start at `0`, not `1`. So the `10`th element of `s` is `s[9]`.

---

2. You attempt to assign a string literal to an array or more specific an array element, which is not permissible in C. The only exception is the initialization of an array of `char` (assignment at the definition) like it is in the first example.

   To assign an array by a string literal use `strcpy()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[10];
    strcpy(s, "hello");
    printf("s = %s\n",s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because of the way stack is allocated, 
[image: memory layout]

As you can see stack address are descending, meaning that for your variable the end of `s` would touch the beginning your current stack scope.

```
          Stack pointer
S         V
0123456789#PPPPPP
           ^
           Stack guard
```

Usually your stack scope would be padded by stack guard, helping detection of stack smashing if these value would be overwritten. of hardware would detect this.

then coming to you code:

```
s[10] = "hello";
```

would be equivalent to

```
s[10] = {some char pointer}
```

which while not reflecting your intent, could be working.

issue is that you char array is addressable from `0` to `9`, writing at the `10`th offset would be writing out of the array bound (which is for some reason allowed by C) but also right on the stack pointer, which cause to trigger the detection of the stack smashing.